# Sails js find() finding non-existing users

Tags: find, sails.js

I'm trying to build a simple server in SailsJS and encountered a problem: I send a POST request to the service in Sails, and I always get a 200 response, even when there's no matching user in the on-disk DB.

My model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: { type: "string" },
    lastName: { type: "string" }
  }
};
```

My routes file:

```
module.exports.routes = {  
  'post /authTest' : 'UserController.testingAuth'

};
```

My controller:

```
module.exports = {
    testingAuth : function(req, res) {
        var temp = req.param("name");
        sails.log(temp);
        User.find({ name: 'testing123' }).exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                sails.log("inside err block");
                return res.serverError(err);
            }
            sails.log("skipped err block");
            return res.json(user);
        })
    }
};
```

The way I call the service:

```
var testUser = { name: 'notMyName', lastName: 'myLastName' };
$http.post("http://localhost:1337/authTest", testUser);
```

Then on the SailsJS console I see:

```
debug: notMyName
debug: skipped err block
```

My local DB has just the following though (localDiskDb.db in .tmp):

```
{
  "data": {
    "passport": [],
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "myName",
        "lastName": "myLastName",
        "createdAt": "2017-11-18T17:26:13.609Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-11-18T17:26:13.609Z",
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
// some schema stuff, irrelevant here
}
```

Can someone see anything wrong here? The service receives the posted request object fine, searches for a user that is not in the DB, but finds one anyway?

Comment: Everything is fine here. First of all, find() returns an array (empty if no results, populated if there is results. Second, yes you are posting with data but the fixed criteria of 'test123' dont match any records in your database... What is your doubt?

Comment: I see. I wrongly assummed that if no user is found, I'll get the "err" back rather than an empty array. The hardcoded "testing123" is on purpose, to test a no-match-found case.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
User.find({ name: 'testing123' }).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            sails.log("inside err block");
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        sails.log("skipped err block");
        return res.json(user);
    })
```

to

```
User.findOne({ name: 'testing123' }).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            sails.log("inside err block");
            return res.serverError(err);
        } else if(user){
            // user found here
            return res.json(user);
        } else {
             //no user found
             return res.json(null);
        }
    })
```

If you want to stick with `find()`:

```
User.find({ name: 'testing123' }).exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        sails.log("inside err block");
        return res.serverError(err);
    } else if(users.length == 0) {
          //users is empty array of results
          return res.json(users)
    } else {
          //users is array of N records with criteria 'testing123' in field 'name'
          return res.json(users);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, with the previous comment this makes sense, an empty array comes back when nothing is found. Kinda off-topic, but would you recommend this way to handle authentication? The frontend is in ionic. I've been looking into token-based approach too.

Comment: Sort of, you still need to issue a token or register the session server-side... Hashing the password with bcrypt and checking for it. Passport can be very good but also overkill.